# Dynamically added control attribute shows up as controls=" " instead of controls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a instagram video fetcher to a website and would like to add the control as default but when I add the control attribute it shows up wrong.

This is what I have for now.

```
if( photo.type == 'video' ){
instagramPhoto = '<div class="instagram-photo '+ photo.type +'">';
instagramPhoto +=   '<video width="615" height="618" poster="'+ photo.images.low_resolution.url +'">';
instagramPhoto +=   '  <source src="'+ videoURL +'"controls>';
instagramPhoto +=   '</video>';
instagramPhoto += '</div>';
```

The string shows up like this

```
<video width="615" height="618" controls=" ">
```

Instead of

```
<video width="615" height="618" controls>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @Reigel yes, the control doesn't show up, but lets say that I edit my html from the chrome developer tool and just write controls, than the control shows up, But as Rituraj says as an answer bellow. maybe its the browser that bothering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

different browser show attribute in different way

here you made attribute **control**

without assign any value so some browser initialize with default value like in  **mozilla** assign by  **controls=""**  and some not like in **ie** or others assign by  **controls**

so it is good use attribute with some value and use in your code as your requirement